# Symbolic solution for integral that Mathematica can't directly integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

As explored [in this math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694), the integral

$I = \int_{-1}^1\frac1x\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln\left(\frac{2\,x^2+2\,x+1}{2\,x^2-2\,x+1}\right) \ \mathrm dx$

or in code:

```
Integrate[1/x*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]* Log[(2 x^2 + 2 x + 1)/(2 x^2 - 2 x + 1)], {x, -1, 1}]
```

a) cannot be evaluated directly with *Mathematica*; and
b) has the following closed form (symbolic) solution $I=4\,\pi\operatorname{arccot}{\sqrt\phi}$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

In code, this is:

```
4 π ArcCot[Sqrt[GoldenRatio]]
```

Can we find a way to perform this symbolic integration with *Mathematica*?

Comment: have you tried any of the various approaches in the answers to the linked question?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a *partial* answer: making the substitution $x=\cos t$ yields the integral

```
AbsoluteTiming[res = Integrate[Cot[t/2] Tan[t]
                               Log[1 + (4 Cos[t])/(2 - 2 Cos[t] + Cos[2 t])], {t, 0, π}];]
   {1033.99, Null}
```

which is very complicated:

```
LeafCount[res]
   2460
```

but does evaluate to a number that is the same as $4\pi\operatorname{arccot}\sqrt\phi$:

```
{N[res, 20], N[4 π ArcCot[Sqrt[GoldenRatio]], 20]}
   {8.3722116266012756616 + 0.*10^-20 I, 8.3722116266012756616}
```

I've had `FullSimplify[]` work on `res` for eight hours; no progress thus far.

---

### Update

I aborted the evaluation of `FullSimplify[]` after 20 hours. It turns out that a slightly more convoluted route gives a more manageable expression:

```
resf = MapAll[FullSimplify, MapAll[Simplify, MapAll[ComplexExpand, res]]]
   π^2 - 1/2 I π Log[Root[1 - 4868 #1 + 5638 #1^2 - 4868 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 3]]

resf = FullSimplify[ToRadicals[RootReduce[ComplexExpand[resf]]]]
   π^2 - 1/2 π ArcTan[(8 Sqrt[15242 + 20689 Sqrt[5]])/1409]
```

Make a manual transformation:

```
atanRule = ArcTan[u_] :> 2 ArcTan[ToRadicals[RootReduce[(Sqrt[1 + u^2] - 1)/u]]];

resf = FullSimplify[resf /. atanRule]
   π (π - ArcTan[4/31 Sqrt[-22 + 17 Sqrt[5]]])
```

Manually transform again:

```
resf = resf /. atanRule
   π (π - 2 ArcTan[1/2 Sqrt[-2 + Sqrt[5]]])
```

And again:

```
resf = FullSimplify[resf /. ArcTan[u_] :> π/2 - ArcCot[u]]
   2 π ArcTan[2 Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]]]
```

And finally:

```
resf = resf /. atanRule /. ArcTan[u_] :> ArcCot[FullSimplify[1/u]]
   4 π ArcCot[Sqrt[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])]]
```

Answer (score 2):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.**

```
expr = 1/x Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)] *
   Log[(2 x^2 + 2 x + 1)/(2 x^2 - 2 x + 1)];

expr2 = NIntegrate[expr, {x, -1, 1}];
```

Although not practical, you can use [`RootApproximant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html) to reverse engineer from the numerical integration

```
(expr3 = 4 Pi ArcCot[(RootApproximant[Cot[expr2/(4 Pi)]] // ToRadicals) /. 
      5^(1/2) -> 2 GoldenRatio - 1]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rubi can integrate this, but Rubi only does indefinite integration. Using second part of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus  in order to obtain the definite integration then proved hard, but may be because this is improper integral and one can't really use FTOC on it!

Mathematica can't find limit as `x->1` but can find limit `x->0`.

The Rubi indefinite result contain many `PolyLog` terms. Tried "Developer`PolyLogSimplify" on it, but that did not help.  I post Rubi output, may be someone has smart way to finish this part.

```
ClearAll[x]
expr=1/x Sqrt[(1+x)/(1-x)] Log[(2x^2+2x+1)/(2 x^2-2x+1)]
anti = Int[expr, x];
anti2 = Developer`PolyLogSimplify[anti]
```

Here it the long result

```
2*ArcTan[Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 - (2*(1 + x))/(1 - x) + (5*(1 + x)^2)/(1 - x)^2)/
     (5 - (2*(1 + x))/(1 - x) + (1 + x)^2/(1 - x)^2)] - 
  2*ArcTanh[Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 - (2*(1 + x))/(1 - x) + (5*(1 + x)^2)/(1 - x)^2)/
     (5 - (2*(1 + x))/(1 - x) + (1 + x)^2/(1 - x)^2)] + 
  Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[-((Sqrt[1 - 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
      (1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))] + Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[-((Sqrt[1 + 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))] + 
  I*Log[(Sqrt[1 - 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])]*
   Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]] + 
  I*Log[(Sqrt[1 + 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])]*
   Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]] - 
  I*Log[-((Sqrt[1 - 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))]*
   Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]] - 
  I*Log[-((Sqrt[1 + 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))]*
   Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]] - 
  Log[(Sqrt[1 - 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])]*
   Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]] - 
  Log[(Sqrt[1 + 2*I] - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])]*
   Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]] + I*Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[-((Sqrt[1 - 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))] - 
  Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[-((Sqrt[1 - 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
      (1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))] - I*Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(Sqrt[1 - 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(Sqrt[1 - 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + I*Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[-((Sqrt[1 + 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))] - 
  Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[-((Sqrt[1 + 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
      (1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))] - I*Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(Sqrt[1 + 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(I + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(Sqrt[1 + 2*I] + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  I*Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 - I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - I*Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - 
  I*Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 - I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + I*Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - 
  Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  I*Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 - I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - I*Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + Log[1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - 
  I*Log[1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 - I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + I*Log[1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*
   Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - 
  Log[1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]]*Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
     (1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + PolyLog[2, (1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
    (1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/
     (1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))] + PolyLog[2, (1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
    (1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/
    (1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + PolyLog[2, (1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
    (1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/
     (1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))] + PolyLog[2, (1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/
    (1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 - Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/
    (1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 - I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - 
  I*PolyLog[2, (1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + I*Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  I*PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 + I*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(I + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] - 
  PolyLog[2, (1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2*I]))] - 
  PolyLog[2, (1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] + 
  PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 - 2*I]*(1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2*I])] - 
  PolyLog[2, (1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  PolyLog[2, -((Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(1 - Sqrt[1 + 2*I]))] - 
  PolyLog[2, (1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])] + 
  PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[1 + 2*I]*(1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]))/(1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*I])]
```

Now

```
Limit[anti2,x->-1]
(*0*)

Limit[anti2,x->1]  (*this is the problem, it gets stuck here*)
```

Rubi and Mathematica are close, but no cigar.

Now to verify Rubi result, Differentiated back the anti-derivative to see it gives back the integrand (or constant shifted version of it). This is what I get

```
expr0=Assuming[Element[x,Reals],FullSimplify[D[anti2,x]]]
(*     (2*Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]*ArcTanh[(2*x)/(1 + 2*x^2)])/x *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting the above against the original integrand to check, shows they are the same! So Rubi result is valid, but may be not optimal

```
{Plot[expr0,{x,-1,1},PlotLabel->"Rubi"],Plot[expr,{x,-1,1},PlotLabel->"original"]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]